# High tides at Venice

Tags: tides, coastal

I read somewhere that the new [MOSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSE_Project) system can withstand a maximum rise in water of about 3m. I was wondering if that extreme case will happen on the coast line of Lido di Venezia, there will be a rising of the water with a consequent problem at the many beaches along the litoral. What are they expecting? Venice would be, hopefully, saved while Lido will suffer high level of water on the beaches. And more important: how much above the sea level is the highest point of Lido di Venezia?

Added: if the highest point at Lido is 3m that would be the only dry place in case of a tide of 3m. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Wikipedia: Highest point 3m. I hope you're not suggesting that the MOSE will make the tides/storm surges higher on Lido by blocking the channel.

Comment: @Spencer why not?

Answer (score 1):

Venice has plans for a new hydraulic flow controlled by levees and a dam during runoff & tidal events as sealevel continues to rise.

This has a brief summary of progress: https://www.citylab.com/life/2016/09/venices-vast-new-flood-barrier-is-almost-here/498935/

[edit]
The context of Venice has 3 parts, the freshwater seasonal and episodic flow including groundwater in a relic delta, this with enough fetch to sea  allowing winds to pile water for days, and, there are seasonal tides with that.

The almost complete solution deals with sediment compaction separately from defense against high water, those solutions have injection strategies, they're dealing with pore-pressure, flow and having clean water in the canals or they stink.

My view, it's analogous to the high water dam against the North Sea that's closed for storms.

Long-term a dam at Gibraltar Strait, 1200-ft deep has been proposed to save history, otherwise we hit 3mm in a year in 2016 of rise, at 600-ppm Antarctica's land ice begins an unstoppable melt as is going on with submerged valley glaciers.

To the question of littoral habitat that's ok unless there's an oil spill, pollutants in runoff are poisoning it pretty fast being an enclosed sea vs oceanic facing littorals from my reading.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer - extract the relevant information from your link so that it is contained directly in your post.

Comment: This is a quite complex solution over years of time, the hydraulics alone have several citations and the question jumps topics, beyond me to organize an concise response thus mine more of opening a door to weeks of study to know the context